# Div stays empty after being loaded with .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I do not see any reason why I could not get fullcalendar to work. I tried a very basic fullcalendar with below code.

**index.php**:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='components/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='components/fullcalendar/lang/de.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='components/fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    lang: 'de',
    events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/e_2_de%23weeknum%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
    });
 });
</script>
```

I checked and all of these files do exist! In `index.php` a `<div>` is filled with `<div id="calendar"></div>` via `.load`. The `.load` action works fine, but the `<div id="calendar">` is always empty!

I tried with the same files separately and that worked fine. I would be very thankful for your help, if you want to take a look at it:

URL: http://bit.ly/1rLA4UY
To see the problem go to *Termine* => *ALLE TERMINE*

The div that appears is filled with `<div id="calendar"></div>` but stays empty instead of showing the fullcalendar/calendar.

Comment: Move <script src="javascript/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> below to <link rel='stylesheet' href='components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />

Comment: I did that but it didn't change anything...

Comment: Try using `$(document).on('click','div.list-wrap a', function(){` instead of `$("div.list-wrap a").click(function(){`

Comment: unfortunately that didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Since `#calendar` does not exist yet when the page has loaded your script will not find it.

You have to run this script after loading the div using `.load()` and not when the document is ready

---

Load the calendar after the div is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Innerhalb der Liste href auslesen und durch # ersetzen, title-Attribut mit dem Wert des href schreiben
    $("div.list-wrap a").each(function () {

        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $(this).attr("title", url).attr("href", "#");

    });

    // per Click entsprechende URL in das DIV laden, aber nur das DIV #seiteninhalt
    $("div.list-wrap a").click(function () {
        var quelle = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#content_small").load(quelle, function () { // after done loading do below
            if (quelle.indexOf('cal.html') > -1) { // check if clicked on cal.html
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ // if clicked on cal.html load the plugin
                    lang: 'de',
                    events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/e_2_de%23weeknum%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic'
                })
            }
            $("#content_small").fadeIn(500);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: .load() is in the index.php before   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        lang: 'de',
  events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/e_2_de%23weeknum%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
    })

});
</script> ist that the way it should work?

Comment: @user2814794 No. Because in order for load to work you first have to click on the button.  The calendar script will run before you press the button (when the page loads). After you pressed the button document ready will not fire again! Please show your script for loading the pages.

Comment: ah ok, I think I do unterstand what you mean! the script for loading content to a div by clicking on links is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HAFnt

Comment: @user2814794 instead of your document ready function change your load function to the one I suggested above

Comment: I changed the function as you recommended but now the #content_small div is not fading in at all when you click on a link...

Comment: @user2814794 yeah I see. You only had to expand your function to the one I wrote not replace it completely >:D . See edit

Comment: well that makes a big change ;) great, it work's just the way I want it to be! And I do unterstand your steps :) thank you very much for your kind help!!!

Comment: one last question about behaviour I don't unterstand: if the cal.html - link is the first category on the menu that is clicked, it needs the script to click twice on the link "ALLE TERMINE" until the calender is loaded. If you have already clicked any other link of the menu and the div where it is loaded to is already "opened" then it works just fine by clicking "ALLE TERMINE" once. Hard to explain, maybe you try the bitly link above, if you are so kind.